# Foreign key constraint is not working in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I read from W3school that this command

```
P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

will work in PLSQL, when I tried this on Sql Developer then It was throwing an exception of

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

after this I replaced this command with following

```
P_Id int, 
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

and it worked, I want to ask whether the first command is not for oracle or is there something wrong with my oracle.

Comment: Don't use w3fools. It's full of errors

Comment: thank you a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreign key` part for an **inline** constraint is invalid. You can only use `references`

```
create table x
(
  p_id integer references persons(p_id)
);
```

Comment: It helps to read a little bit about inline and out-of-line constraints, they cause a fair number of questions on this forum. Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm